# MySQL Query in need of Optimization

Tags: mysql, vb.net, optimization, datagridview

I have a weather station database that I want to view in a Visual Basic .Net Application through a Data Grid View.  The raw data is put in the database by the station every 10 minutes, but I only get one rainfall amount the cumulative rainfall FOR THE ENTIRE YEAR.  In the application I would like to display the amount of rain every observation period and at the bottom show the accumulation for the day.  Everything works, but this query I wrote in MySQL takes forever to run.  Is there any way to optimize this?

### UPDATE:

Sorry, I thought the image would show up better, here is the query:  (The bolded part is what is so slow)

```
SELECT 
      d.RecordIDNumber, 
      d.RecDateTime, 
      d.AirTemp_F_Avg, 
      d.AirTemp_F_Min, 
      DATE_FORMAT(d.AirTemp_F_TMn, '%H:%i') AS 'AirTemp_F_TMn', 
      d.AirTemp_F_Max, 
      DATE_FORMAT(d.AirTemp_F_TMx, '%H:%i') AS 'AirTemp_F_TMx', 
      d.RH_Avg, 
      d.Barometer_iHg, 
      d.BatVolt_V, 
      d.BatVolt_V_Min, 
      d.ETo_in, 
      d.RainYearly_in, 
      d.Solar_Avg, 
      d.WindSpeed_mph_Avg, 
      d.WindSpeed_mph_Max, 
      DATE_FORMAT(d.WindSpeed_mph_TMx, '%H:%i') AS 'WindSpeed_mph_TMx', 
      d.WindSpeed_mph_WVc1, 
      d.Wind_Direction, 
      ROUND(35.74 + 0.6215 * d.AirTemp_F_Avg 
          - 35.75 * POW(d.WindSpeed_mph_Avg, 0.16) 
          + 0.4275 * d.AirTemp_F_Avg * POW(d.WindSpeed_mph_Avg, 0.16),2) AS 'WindChill', 
      ROUND((17.625 - LOG(d.RH_Avg / 100) 
          - ((17.625 * d.AirTemp_F_Avg) / (243.04 + d.AirTemp_F_Avg))), 2) AS 'Dewpoint', 
      d.RainYearly_in - ( SELECT 
                                MIN(d2.RainYearly_in) 
                             FROM 
                                data d2 
                             WHERE 
                                DATE_FORMAT(d2.RecDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') 
                                  = DATE_FORMAT(d.RecDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') ) 
   FROM 
      data d 
   WHERE 
          DATE_FORMAT(d.RecDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-11-01' 
      AND d.RecordIDNumber <> -1 
   ORDER BY 
      d.RecDateTime DESC
```

Comment: The query is terrible (impossible) to read. Paste the code in your question.

Comment: Do you have the correct indexes? (Run `EXPLAIN` in front of this to see how MySQL will execute it.)

Comment: The bolded part doesn't look right: `d.RainYearly_in - (SELECT MIN(d2.RainYearly_in) FROM data d2 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(d2.RecDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') DATE_FORMAT(d.RecDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d'))`.  Is there a missing '='?  Also what does that column mean

Comment: Yes, I think an equals sign got removed when I was copying and pasting, sorry about that.  d.RainYearly_in is the current, right now RainYearly amount from the DB.  MIN(d2.RainYearly) is the RainYain at the beginning of each calendar day during the year.  The DATE_FORMAT is necessary to get that day and not all records (it is a DATETIME column) being the same.  So now I subtract (Current YearlyRain - StartOfDay Yearlyrain) to get DailyRain. It takes a long time to run and I tried to index RainYearly.  Thanks for you help on this.

Comment: @Kevin, I formatted query for readability and found per others you are missing the "=" (which I put in) in the field subquery for MIN(RainYearly) factor.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the query cleanup, your query in the field-level for yearly rain can probably be optimized if you just apply the same WHERE clause as the outer.  Since you are only trying to query for a single day, and appears you get multiple readings in a day, you are trying to find the lowest of that particular day... Is that correct?

```
d.RainYearly_in - ( SELECT 
                          MIN(d2.RainYearly_in) 
                       FROM 
                          data d2 
                       WHERE 
                          DATE_FORMAT(d2.RecDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d')  ='2013-11-01' )
```

Since your outer query is only concerned with 2013-11-01, and your inner is based on matching the outer date, then the inner date can just look directly for the same date.

You might even consider doing via a JOIN to a second query on just the MIN() factor for the date in question

```
     d.RainYearly_in - JustMin.MinRain as Whatever
   FROM 
      data d,
      ( SELECT
              MIN(d2.RainYearly_in) as MinRain
           FROM 
              data d2 
           WHERE 
              DATE_FORMAT(d2.RecDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-11-01' ) JustMin
```

Since you are only doing a 1 day, the JUSTMIN will only return the one date in question and apply itself to every entry recorded for the day since there is no explicit JOIN or WHERE clause between the two.  Now, if you run for multiple day span, you WOULD need to do a join on the date in question.

An additional note... By using your WHERE clauses applying a "DATE_FORMAT()", you are not getting a benefit of a date index as it has to compute it to compare.  You would be better off doing something like

```
WHERE d2.RecDateTime >= '2013-11-01' and d2.RecDateTime < '2013-11-02'
```

And if you are passing a value to the stored procedure, let it be a date, then you could do

```
WHERE d2.RecDateTime >= dateParameter 
  and d2.RecDateTime <  DATE_ADD(dateParameter, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I only hard coded the date for testing... The vb app passes the date in as part of a WHERE clause it builds for the SP.  In other words I would like to make it efficient and generic though I could use a MySql SUBSTRING to obtain the date, since it is always the first item in the string.

Comment: @Kevin, see tail-end of revised answer regarding where, and parameter and better index utilization.